# How to deploy and update C# the application with SQL database?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2013, deployment, sql-server-2014

I'm working on a C# desktop application with SQL database, and I'm about to finish but I have two problems.
First One, I want to deploy the application with the database so I can go to the client and install the application with the database.
Second One, I want to work on another features and go to the client and install the update without losing the data on the database, any help please ?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an installer for your desktop application. Using installshield.
2. If you need the data to transfer on client, back up database. Else, generate script for your database schema. Your client should have an installed SQL Database.

If there's an update on your application, just update the app itself because data on  the database is another matter.

Comment: If I'm gonna make a .bak of the SQL Database how to attach it with the installer and Am I need to install SQL Server on the client machine ?

Comment: @AhmedEmad installer of your app will create .exe there's no need to attach it with your installer. just give the .exe and .bak file to your client. yes, sql server is needed on the client.

Comment: really thank you for your help
I hope that I can ask you again if I'm facing any trouble :D

Comment: @AhmedEmad sure anytime, just beep me up!

Comment: Do I need to change the connection string when going to the client machine ?
and Is there is a way that I can prevent installing SQL Server ?

Comment: @AhmedEmad yes. your connection string should be located in your app.config.. no.. its required to have sql server

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET then automate the build process. You can use Nant with build file, tasks to install your application. This tasks can include scripts to run.

Nant uses build file which has structure like

```
<project name="RohitLib" default="clean">
<property name="build.dir" value="build"/>
<target name="clean">
<delete dir="${build.dir}" verbose="true" failonerror="false"/>
</target>
</project>
```

Include task execute to run your script like  sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\updateScript.sql.

Add any additional tasks you need to run for your application to run.  You can get complete list of tasks from http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.92/help/tasks/.